# WordPress Customized Theme White Background Issue

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Ok, So I have customized a **Twenty Fourteen** theme from **WordPress**. Everything works find minus a couple things. The top header shows a white background if its stretched. The footer also shows a white background if its stretched. The funny thing is there is no white background in the **css code**? I have even looked in the **functions.php** to see if it was hard coded issue and nothing. I tried to inspect the element and all it says it shows up before and after? I tried adding background: none; to all the before and after codes and still shows up. Does anyone have a clue I have linked the site I am developing on.

**Website:** http://www.soslidesigns.com/flh

If worst comes to worst I can simply re-design it and I have a feeling I might have to. Would be nice to get your guys feedback. Like I said I have tried everything I could think of simple issues like this always through me in a loop.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: So people don't complain I am not promoting anything you can clearly see my issue. I am coming here because no one was able to help me on the WordPress forums thanks again!

Comment: Hopefully, you realize that the next time you update Wordpress, all your work will potentially be overwritten. You should be making a child theme if you want to modify an existing theme.

Comment: I changed the name of the theme and used the latest template files. Its not like I posted this after an update for WordPress. The issue is within' the CSS I am missing the file some how.

Comment: your first question The top header shows a white background if its stretched: its not header it your body which shoiwng white background.you can change the background-color or background-image according to your need, and same thing with your second question that The footer also shows a white background if its stretched.

Comment: Yes the header/menu and footer with the white background I want fixed. I added a background: transparent!important; to the code for both and it still shows up? I am not sure why this is happening I may just end up re-doing the template.

Answer (score 0):

Your white background write [here](http://www.soslidesigns.com/flh/wp-content/plugins/bwp-minify/min/?f=flh/wp-content/themes/flh-mobile/style.css,flh/wp-content/plugins/mp3-jplayer/css/dark.css) in **body** (background:none). This set white background to all site. If you need set another color to header - change background in **.site** (in this file)

Comment: Not sure if I get what you are trying to say? Are you saying I should have a color instead of saying none in the CSS...